# How to debug an apache virtual host configuration?

Tags: apache, debugging, virtualhost

Once again, I have a problem with my apache virtual host configuration. (The default configuration is used instead of my specific one).

The problem is not really the misconfiguration but how to solve it.

Does anyone has good advices to do resolve this kind of problem quickly?

Some more informations.

The default conf file is this one:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And the virtual host config that doesn't apply is this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8088/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip.ip.ip.ip:8088/
ServerName wiki.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: DNS checks are also useful e.g. flushdns https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/clear-the-local-dns-cache-in-osx/ https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-flush-dns

Answer (score 226, accepted):

## Syntax check

To check configuration files for syntax errors:

```bash
# Red Hat-based (Fedora, CentOS), Arch-based and OSX
httpd -t

# Debian-based (Ubuntu)
apache2ctl -t

# MacOS
apachectl -t
```

## List virtual hosts

To list all virtual hosts, and their locations:

```bash
# Red Hat-based (Fedora, CentOS), Arch-based and OSX
httpd -S

# Debian-based (Ubuntu)
apache2ctl -S

# MacOS
apachectl -S
```

Comment: `-S` is a synonym for `-t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` so those two are the same

Comment: For Windows, (if you are using xampp), you have these same commands at: \xampp\apache\bin

Comment: For Wamp: `c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -S`

Comment: That's very useful, thank you but it is not enough, I got some trouble with a vhost that it should be used and is not, i dont know why, I wish to get logs about how apache choose the vhost.

Comment: Is there any way to make Apache add a message to the error file or elsewhere when an actual access comes in for a virtual or main host giving dynamic information about which host was chosen?

I have tried

LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so   
...   
LogMessage "Debug 1" hook=all

Comment: windows found this (on git basch console):    ./httpd.exe -S

Answer (score 33):

Here's a command I think could be of some help :

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

You'll get a list of all the vhosts, you'll know which one is the default one and you'll make sure that your syntax is correct (same as apachectl configtest suggested by yojimbo87).

You'll also know where each vhost is declared. It can be handy if your config files are a mess. ;)

Answer (score 28):

If you are trying to debug your virtual host configuration, you may find the Apache -S command line switch useful. That is, type the following command:

```
httpd -S
```

This command will dump out a description of how Apache parsed the configuration file. Careful examination of the IP addresses and server names may help uncover configuration mistakes. (See the docs for the [httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) program for other command line options).

Comment: In Apache2 this is `apache2ctl -S`

Comment: or alternately `APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data /usr/sbin/apache2 -S`

Answer (score 17):

First check out [config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html) files for syntax errors with `apachectl configtest` and then look into apache error [logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html).

Comment: I have no syntax error because my server reboot and reload the configuration without any problem. I don't know in which log I could find details about my configuration.

Comment: Error logs are usually located in '/var/log/apache2/error.log' file.

Comment: You can also use "apache2ctl -t".

Answer (score 15):

I had a new VirtualHost configuration file that was not showing when using the `apachectl -S` command.  After much head scratching I realised that my file did not have suffix ".conf". Once I renamed the file with that suffix my Vhost started showing and working!

Answer (score 10):

I recently had some issues with a VirtualHost. I used `a2ensite` to enable a host but before running a restart (which would kill the server on fail) I ran

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Which gives you some info about what's going on with your virtual hosts. It's not perfect, but it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I found my own mistake, I did not add log file name:
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2

And this path: 
     Directory "/usr/share/doc/"
Did not contain website sources.

After I changed these two, all worked. 
Interestingly, apache did not issue any errors, just did not open my website silently on my Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: Good answer, help me find similar issue. All syntax and -S vhosts correct, still wrong site served. Turned out to be :80 and :443 has the same access log file, which seemed to confuse things. Separate file for each port, and sites started working.

Answer (score 2):

a very important tool is

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

it showed me that the file that i was fixing and mending
was in fact included by a file that was itself not included.

thank everybody