# Apache VirtualHosts on AWS EC2 not working

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up a VirtualHost on my AWS EC2 Linux server. However, it continues to direct the request to the default page.

I've installed apache and when I create an index file in `/var/www/html/` it displays as expected.

However, when I add a `*.conf` virtual host it just reverts the default page.

I've created my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/{myvhost.conf}` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/username/www/public"
    ServerName ec2-13-55-0-7.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com

</VirtualHost>
```

The document root has been created at /home/username/www/public and I've added a custom `index.html` file, perms set to 755.

`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf` is uncommented in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Restarted apache.

But default page is displayed and not my `/home/username/www/public`.
Why?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

First it would be nice if you added some [`Directory` directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) to your root folder:

```
<Directory "/home/username/www/public/">
  allow from all
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Or ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/226986/783)):

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options Indexes
</LocationMatch>
```

Second, you can [debug what Apache understand of the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568100/6309):

```
# Check for syntax error
apachectl -t
# List VirtualHost
apachectl -S

# both checks:
apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

Of course, check the [log files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html).