# How to set virtual host in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I tried to set up virtual host in xampp for my website. For this I set host file like:

```
127.0.0.1           siteurl
```

I am adding code in httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/foldername"
      ServerName siteurl
      <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that put the siteurl in browser then, I got the xampp dashboard. How can I get my website by entering my siteurl.
can you please help me anyone.

Comment: Your settings seem correct. Check your apache `httpd.conf` to see if your `httpd-vhosts.conf` is included or commented out. If the line starts with a `#` then remove the `#`. Then restart apache

Comment: No. Its already included in httpd.conf file

Comment: DNS gets cached. Try running `ipconfig /flushdns` in your command window after you update hosts file

Comment: Please share more details. Did you restart the servers properly, such that the changed configuration gets read?

Comment: I got this answer

Answer (score 0):

You're `Directory` needs the absolute path to your `DocumentRoot` and you were closing that tag, remove the `/`. Also, windows requires `\` instead of `/` in the root paths. Also I opened up your permissions a little for testing. Yours seemed very restrictive and could cause problems in getting it up and running

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
      DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\foldername"
      ServerName siteurl
      <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\foldername">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All  
        # AllowOverride none 
        # Require all denied
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, when you update your `hosts` file, you need to clear your DNS cache which usually happens when you restart, but you can also run this command in your command window:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: I tried with this code, but this is not working for me. Again shows the same page

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: ok, I updated the answer. Your paths need to use backslashes . please change and restart apache

Comment: I tried with these code also, but no change

Comment: Hmm.. those were all deal-breaking errors. Are you sure your vhosts file is loading? Try running these command line tests located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568100/1772933

Comment: What do you see when you run this command in the command window? `a2query -s`

Comment: I added another edit to my answer. Please try that and restart apache. Thanks

Comment: I got this answer. I changed my xampp version. My previous version is not supporting in my files. thats s the reason. thankyou for your support

Answer (score -1):

I changed my xampp version. My previous version is not supporting in my files. that's the reason. thankyou for your support